# use sapply on a column of a data frame? - R

Tags: r

I have the this data frame:

```r
df=data.frame("fg"=c("bv65","bv89"),"gh"=c(87,21))
```

and I need to delete the substring "bv" in the column "fg". I did it this way:

```r
sapply(df$fg,FUN=gsub(pattern="bv",replacement = "",x=df$fg))
```

but I get this error:

Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'gsub(pattern = "bv", replacement = "", x = df$fg)' is not a function, character or symbol

Why?

Comment: `df$fg <- sub('bv', '', df$fg)`

Answer (score 1):

`sub`/`gsub` are vectorized. You can use them for all the values in the column. Perhaps, you might also want to convert the values to numeric.

```
df$fg <- as.numeric(sub('bv', '', df$fg))
df
#  fg gh
#1 65 87
#2 89 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Ronak's solution is the way to go since `gsub()`/`sub()` can deal with vectors. But in case you wanted to know what was missing from your current approach:

```
sapply(df$fg, FUN = function(x) sub(pattern="bv", replacement="", x))
# Or simply
sapply(df$fg, sub, pattern="bv", replacement="")
```